# LoopbackJS Get authenticated UserId to be stored against a model without exposing it via the API

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, loopbackjs

I have the below "Content" model in Loopback which requires an authenticated user to access. 
Each piece of Content can be created by only one user. (user is inherited from the Loopback internal User model) So when creating Content I would like the UserId to be stored in the Content record. 
However, i'd like this to happen behind the scenes without having to pass through the userId via the API.
I've had a play with relations, but this doesn't seem to be working out..

```js
{
  "name": "Content",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "BooId": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "Name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "Language": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "default": "en-gb"
    },
    "Version": {
      "type": "number",
      "default": 1
    },
    "Text": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "Created": {
      "type": "date",
      "defaultFn": "now"
    },
    "Tags": {
      "type": [
        "string"
      ],
      "default": []
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": [],
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would create a new relation for the content. So I would add the relation to your Content model:

```
"relations": {
  "author": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "user", // <-- your user model name
    "foreignKey": ""
  }
}
```

Then, you could use the `before save` hook to set the `userId` on your content model.

Or, you can simply just download this mixin to do it for you.

https://github.com/akkonrad/loopback-author-mixin

Comment: Tried using the mixin which is populating the userId nicely thank you. However, authorId is being exposed out via the API. Any way of suppressing that?

Comment: Got it hidden by adding this: "hidden": ["authorId", "userId"] in the content model

Comment: The mixin seems to be saving under "authorId" even though i specified "userId" here:     "authorField": "userId"

Comment: hey @NiceYellowEgg, package fixed and published, please check if it works now as it suppose to

Comment: @NiceYellowEgg make sure you're updating the mixin module (now its version 1.0.2) and then restart your server. I've just checked it with a custom project and it works with the custom field. I've shared the project [here](https://github.com/akkonrad/loopback-test-modules) on github, to reproduce you have to create new user, login, and then create new Article with api call, you should see `papaId` field of the given user. Make sure you're logged in, otherwise this field won't be set at all